# "Muted" Condition detection for RemoteAudioTrack in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm facing a challenge with detecting a muted(disabled) track when this event happens:

```
Room.on("trackSubscribed", (track, participant))
```

I can subscribe to a separate track events (enabled/disabled) later after the track is connected, however if the track was muted when it was connected how do i determine that?

When i look into the track properties (console log `track` after `trackSubscribed` event) there is a `mediaStreamTrack` inside and it has:

```
-enabled (true)
-muted (false)
```

But both of these properties are always set to abbove mentioned values regardless of whether the track is muted or not upon initial connect.

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Twilio video only has control over and knowledge of muting the media stream, not the end user's microphone. Is that what you are talking about here?

Comment: It's not about muting the remote audio stream(and/or device) but rather detecting whether the remote user track(user called `localAudioTrack.disable()`) is muted upon room join, that's it

Comment: Have you checked whether the [`AudioTrack` object `isEnabled`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.19.2/docs/AudioTrack.html#toc1__anchor) rather than looking at the `mediaStream` itself?

Comment: @philnash according to docs(https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.19.2/docs/RemoteAudioTrack.html) remote audio track does not have this property :(

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but I managed to do it.
I listen for subsribed tracks like so:

```
this.remoteParticipant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
    publication.on('subscribed', track => this.onTrackSubscribed(track))
    .on('unsubscribed', track => this.twilioService.detachRemoteTrack(track));
});
```

In which remoteParticipant is of type RemoteParticipant. And initialize the participant 'isMuted' variable in the following method:

```
function onTrackSubscribed(track) {
    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
        this.isMuted = !track.isEnabled;
        track.on('disabled', (track) => this.isMuted = true);
        track.on('enabled', (track) => this.isMuted = false);
    }
}
```

This should be done for all participants, but in my case there is only one.
Hope it helps!